# Cannot remove div from 3rd party script with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to remove an element from a 3rd party script that loads a couple iframes after everything on the page is loaded, and for some reason, my code does not work.

```
    jQuery(window).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.sharefooter-modern')
        .css("display", "none");
        console.log("removed2");
    });
```

I've tried window onload, document ready and some other things but the code still gets triggered before everything is actually loaded.

Html I am trying to remove:

```
<div class="sharefooter-modern">
```

It is loaded in iframe with new html body

Full html with iframe https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzMbmN I am trying to remove the piece with "Viral Loops"

Comment: html to see wich 3rd party ty. you want to remove .sharefooter-modern the 3rd ?

Comment: The iframe src is an url from the same domaine?

Comment: Is it inside one of the iframes?

Comment: to point to an iframe we need is name and source URL if is or not a cross domain, html iframe is needed too.

Comment: it is within iframe, updated with full form code

Comment: @user3166813 you can try the code ;), gl.

Comment: can you tell me if the Iframe is domain facebook? if isn't running just replace #component mean id="component" and add the good iframe id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is nothing I can do to hide the element due to cross-origin policy, but I fixed my specific issue using another approach - I placed iframe in div with fixed height to cut the bottom and set overflow:hidden. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this the commented one is the way, if you got multiple div class .sharefooter-modern and you want to display none only the 3rd and the other is to close all or one of them. Regards.

```
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
    //jQuery("#component").contents().find('.sharefooter-modern:nth-child(3)').css("display", "none");
    jQuery("#component").contents().find(".sharefooter-modern").css("display", "none");
    console.log("removed2");
});
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't work, script triggered before iframe content is loaded for some reason... @headmax

Comment: the question if is a cross domain isn't for the fun ;), because if the iframe domain is no allowed cross origin you can't do anything. but if the domain is the same isn't normal.